# Dynamycally add multiple fragments in FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, dynamic, android-framelayout

I'm am trying to add dynamycally multiple fragments I'm creating to a framelayout, using FragmentTransaction's add() method. Each time I try to do it, Fragments are just replacing one an other.

Here is my code :

```
public class FragmentMerchandSearch extends Fragment {


    public FragmentMerchandSearch() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_merchand_search, container, false);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            Fragment newFragment = new FragmentMerchandPresentation();

            ft.add(R.id.container_merchand_presentation_for_search, newFragment);

        }
        ft.commit();

        return view;
    }
}
```

Here is the code of FragmentMerchandPresentation:

```
public class FragmentMerchandPresentation extends Fragment {

    public FragmentMerchandPresentation(){

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_presentation_merchand, container, false);


        return view;
    }
}
```

Here is XML of fragment_merchand_search:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/container_merchand_presentation_for_search">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And XML of fragment_presentation_merchand:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hey !"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are adding your fragments inside a FrameLayout, this means one is above another.

To add them vertically, use a `LinearLayout` as a container.

Just change your `fragment_merchand_search.xml` to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_merchand_presentation_for_search"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works! 
I thought I could only add fragments to a FrameLayout.

Comment: Glad to help. `FrameLayout` works like a `RelativeLayout`: You have to say where each child goes. Other way, they will all the at top left. `LinearLayout` puts one below another. Mark as answer if you can =)

Answer (score 1):

Just change this line:

```
ft.add(R.id.container_merchand_presentation_for_search, newFragment);
```

to this:

```
ft.replace(R.id.container_merchand_presentation_for_search, newFragment);
```